# function makepoint postgresql 9.1 error postgis

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.1, postgis

Migrating postgres 8.4 to 9.1 and moving my project to a new server I get this error

> ERROR: function makepoint(unknown, unknown) does not exist LINE 4: distance_sphere(makepoint('14.2995419','41.0310868'),mak... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Googling I saw that could be a problem with postgis ... 
then I have followed this guide
http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20Ubuntu1204src and I installed everything on the server ...

Nothing works ... and I'm in danger of becoming insane ... 
Does anyone know how to fix it!?

Comment: Maybe [ST_distance_sphere](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Distance_Sphere.html)?

Comment: @DrColossos is right, also [`ST_MakePoint`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html). I think all, or at least most, of the PostGIS spatial functions gained an `ST_` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out previously, these functions were previously called "makepoint" and "distance_sphere", but later renamed with a "ST_" prefix (ST = "spatial type").

A really simple solution is to add the [`legacy.sql`](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/browser/tags/2.0.6/postgis/legacy.sql.in.c) functions to either your `template_postgis` (if used) or your target database using something like:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-2.0/legacy.sql
```

Comment: Interesting idea and will solve the OP's immediate problem. In my experience, it is often better to cleanly upgrade though, and some of the functions will have been enhanced in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

From the error it would seem that you are enclosing your points in quotes, hence the complaint about unknown, unknown. ST_Makepoint will expect two double precision numbers as input. You should also prefix all spatial functions with ST_, as has been stated in the comments.

If you run the following from a psql prompt:

```
\df ST_MakePoint
```

you will see the 3 versions that are supported, for 2, 3 and 4 dimensions, all taking doubles.

For example:

```
select st_distance_sphere(st_makepoint(14.2995419,41.0310868), st_makepoint(15.2995419,40.0310868)) as dist;
```

returns 139665.10 m

For what is is worth, the ST_ is considered standard's compliant. Oracle uses ST_ before all its spatial functions, as does Postgres/Postgis, MySQL supports both ST_ and just straight function names and Microsoft decided to drop the underscore altogether when they implemented spatial sql in SQL Server 2008, so you have STUnion, for example.